# Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject using await/async

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I'm loading model3d in  ModelLoader and path it to TaskViewModel using async/await construction.

But I've got an error: "System.ArgumentException: 'Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject."

How can I fix it. Model should be loaded on another thread.

AsyncDelegateCommand  - works with Task

```
internal abstract class TaskViewModel : ViewModel
{
    private readonly AsyncDelegateCommand loadCommand;
    private readonly IModelLoader modelLoader;
    private Model3D model;

    public TaskViewModel(IModelLoader modelLoader)
    {
        this.modelLoader = modelLoader;
        loadCommand = new AsyncDelegateCommand(LoadAsync, () => CanLoad);
    }

    public ICommand LoadCommand => loadCommand;

    public bool CanLoad
    {
        get => canLoad;
        set => SetProperty(ref canLoad, value); // generate PropertyChanged
    }

    public Model3D Model
    {
        get => model;
        set => SetProperty(ref model, value);
    }

    private async Task LoadAsync()
    {
    string path = "somePath"
    Model3D model3D = await modelLoader.LoadAsync(path);
    Model = model3D;
    }
}

internal interface IModelLoader
{
    Task<Model3D> LoadAsync(string path);
}

internal sealed class ModelLoader : IModelLoader
{
    private readonly ModelImporter importer = new ModelImporter();
    private readonly Material material = new DiffuseMaterial(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Beige));

    public ModelLoader()
    {
        importer.DefaultMaterial = material;
    }

    public Task<Model3D> LoadAsync(string path)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Load(path), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    }

    private Model3D Load(string path)
    {
        return importer.Load(path);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't generally create a control on one thread and then interact with it one another one, but a frozen freezable can be shared across threads so you can try to freeze the `Model3D` before you return it:

```
private Model3D Load(string path)
{
    var model = importer.Load(path);
    model.Freeze();
    return model;
}
```

Please refer to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/freezable-objects-overview) for more information about freezables.

Comment: I've got an error  at model.Freeze() : System.InvalidOperationException: 'The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.'

Comment: You need to call Freeze() on the thread where you create the Model3D.

Comment: I don't understand, I imported model, than freeze it, and got the same error. Even if I call  Model3D model= importer.Load(path, Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher, true).

Comment: I don't know what importer.Load does. Did you try to freeze it in this method?

Comment: Sorry, ModelImporter is class of HelixToolkit.Wpf library, I haven't access to it.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't change the fact that you need to freeze the Model3D on the thread on which it was created. If the CanFreeze property returns false, you cannot freeze it and then you won't be able to interact with it on another dispatcher thread.

Comment: But CanFreeze returns true

Comment: I have find solution, I should create ModelImporter  in the same thread) @mm8 thank you.